terminology related to inducing a total order
Imagine I have 10 students in an elementary school. I believe it is proper to say the following: The students' age induces a total order on the students (assuming no 2 students have the exact same age).  However, suppose I consider a discrete category like the grade of the student, and further suppose that at least 2 of the students are in the same grade.  I would like to say something like the following: the students' grades induce a total order on the students.  However, students who are in the same grade map to the same value. Thus, if I consider the set into which the students are mapped, it is smaller than the set of students. Can I still say that the students' grade induces a total order on the students?  I believe that a more precise statement would be, there are multiple total orders on the students consistent with their assignment to grades.  For example if Alice, Bob, and Charlie are in 2nd, 3rd, and 3rd grades respectively, then their ordering is consistent with the total orders a<=b<=c and also a<=c<=b. However, this is cumbersome, and I'm looking for a more compact way to say it.
To summarize, I would like to say that a non-injective mapping induces a total order on a set, but I'm  not sure that is valid terminology. Thanks for any help.

I think you might be interested in the concept of Preorder

A function $f : A \to B$, when $B$ is equipped with the structure of a total preorder $- \leq -$, induces a "pulled back" total preorder on $A$ given by $f(-) \leq f(-)$. If in addition $f$ is injective and $\leq$ is antisymmetric (hence $B$ is a total order), then the induced total preorder on $A$ is also antisymmetric (hence a total order).

Why would $f$ need to be injective to induce a total order?

@user3716267 I've rephrased. The point is that injectivity guarantees that the order is antisymmetric.

Oh god; i've found myself in a rabbithole re: terminology and realize there are unfortunately many meanings of the word "total" in this case; I learned in a context where we strictly called those "linear orders" and reserved total for another meaning.
I hate nomenclature.  Thanks for the edit.

@user3716267 Now I'm curious: what is the other meaning of "total" you know of?

The other meaning is simply "not partial."

I don't see the difference between that and "total", or rather I don't know how to make sense of "not partial", since "partial order" is an atomic structure you can have on a set (transitive, reflexive, antisymmetric binary relation), rather than it being an order that has the property of being partial.

You can make sense of it just fine if you relax the scale-of-resolution at which you're resolving natural language to mathematical language.  The fact that "total" is an adjective does not mean that "total order" must mean a strict refinement of "order."  In contexts where you have a lot of both partial and non-partial orders, it becomes convenient to be able to quickly distinguish.

Distinguish between what? I just don't understand what you mean by "total order" if it's not what I mean by "total order" (transitive, reflexive, antisymmetric, linear binary relation) and it's not "partial order" (transitive, reflexive, antisymmetric binary relation). What third thing are you referring to?

I removed the article link because the article itself conflates notation at several points, on closer inspection.  The relevant bit: we can distinguish between two elements not being comparable, and two elements being nonequal but order-equivalent.  You've used "preorder" to name this - in my experience this is what "total" meant, and your "total" is called "linear."

Wikipedia seems to call the property that I think the OP is actually confused about "strictness," which I suppose is about as good as "linearity."

Thanks very much!  Preorder and total preorder are exactly the concepts I needed!

@ErikLearned-Miller If you're happy with the answer (which elaborates on something I alluded to in a comment, so I agree with this) then perhaps you'll consider to accept it as the (or, in other contexts, a) right answer. See What should I do when someone answers my question? and other articles in the Help center (link at the bottom). Specifically, "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." Best wishes.
